# check for duplicates in Core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, duplicates, magicalrecord

i found this code somewhere, can't really remember. How ever i can't get it to work properly. my Entity is named Hovedmenu
.But i don't know what to put into the sortDescriptor no matter what i put in there it returns nil 0 objects.
In my Hovedmenu i have attributes of menuPunkt numberRow date. In menuPunkt there should be data or is data of "Start"

how do i get this code working ? i'm trying to use it against duplicates in my core data

```
-(void)checkForDuplicates
{
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Hovedmenu"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"students"
                                                           ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];

NSError *Fetcherror;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext
                                    executeFetchRequest:request error:&Fetcherror]     mutableCopy];

if (!mutableFetchResults) {
// error handling code.
}

if ([[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"users"]
 containsObject:name.text]) {
//notify duplicates
return;
 }
else
{
 //write your code to add data
}
}
```

Comment: What are the students and users keys? From the original? Duplicate objects or duplicate property values? Why not fetch then create a set from the array and compare the counts?

Comment: @wain no idea how to make that on the top of my head sadly. students and users are from the original code i found. i don't know what to put in those two places

Comment: Those should both be attributes on your Core Data entity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the sort descriptor and use a set to remove duplicates:

```
NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext
                                executeFetchRequest:request error:&Fetcherror];

if (!fetchResults) {
    // error handling code.
}

NSArray *items = [fetchResults valueForKey:@"menuPunkt"];
NSSet *distinctItems = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:items];

if (items.count > distinctItems.count) {
    NSLog(@"Thar be dupes aboard ship lad");
}
```

The main issue is that you aren't 100% clear on what a duplicate is in your context. So you might want to change the `menuPunkt` key to something else.

Comment: im useing magicalrecord so the mangedObjectContext needs to be [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] i believe how ever it returns nil still ??

Comment: hmm now it returns 0 objects

Comment: think it needs to be a NSMutableArray perhaps ?

Comment: No, there is no predicate so it means that the context reference is nil or there are no objects in the store...

Comment: doesn't work. still see duplicates even tho it says 0 objects
how come when i use iCloud it has multiple duplicates but if i don't use iCloud it works ?

Comment: just putting a breakpoint little after the line and viewing it

Comment: plus i can see the actual data in iPad simulator

Comment: And you checked the context reference is set? What data in the sim - how? The fetch is trivial so what is different about it and however else you're using the context?

Comment: well it's a uitableview getting populated with data from Core Data. if i turn on iCloud in magicalrecord i get duplicates each time i change version. if i turn off iCloud i can change version and it prober removes and updates the core data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45953/discussion-between-wain-and-kennyvb)